# .animate() not working with a div, but working when using it with paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to animate a div inside a section. When I call .animate() on its opacity and display, it does nothing, but if I call it on a paragraph inside it, it works. My guess is it has something to do with the .find(). Any ideas?

HTML:

```
        <section class="ac closeddiv" id="design">
            <img src="images/designIcon.png" alt="design" />
                <div class="actxt">
                    <h2>Design</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
        </section>
        <section class="ac opendiv" id="web">
            <img src="images/webIcon.png" alt="web development" />
                <div class="actxt">
                    <h2>Web Development</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
        </section>
        <section class="ac closeddiv" id="marketing">
            <img src="images/smmIcon.png" alt="social media marketing" />
                <div class="actxt">
                    <h2>Social Media Marketing</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
        </section>
```

CSS:

```
.ac img{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

.ac{
    width:33%;
    float:left;
    height:400px;   
    overflow:hidden;
}
.opendiv{
    float:left;
    width:60%;  
}
.closeddiv{
    float:left;
    width:10%;  
}
.actxt{
    opacity:0;
    float:right;
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".ac").click(function(){

    $(this).siblings(".ac").addClass( "closeddiv", 1000, "easeOutQuad" );
    $(this).removeClass( "closeddiv opendiv", 1000, "easeOutQuad" );
    $(this).siblings(".ac").find(".actxt").css("opacity","0").css("display","none");
    $(this).addClass( "opendiv", 1000, "easeOutQuad" );
    $(this).find(".actxt").delay(1000).animate({opacity:1, display:"inline-block"},1000,"easeOutQuad");
});   });
```

I have linked both jQuery and jQuery UI before the script. Even if i call .find() with a div, not it's class, its still not working.

Comment: it work if you remove `display:none` from `.actxt` https://jsfiddle.net/eywk3jm1/ you can also call `show()` in animate callback.

Comment: It actually only works with the show(), only runs right once right without it for some reason.Anyway, thanks a lot!